# Can I increase decimal places with the SwiftUI .currency format style?

Tags: swiftui

I want to use the .currency format style on my Text and TextField but it limits it to 2 decimal places, and I need up to 3 or 4, for instance fuel or stock prices.

In this example the price is rounded to $2.10. Am I stuck with using .number or a custom NumberFormatter?

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var price = 2.099
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Price", value: $price, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
        Text("\(price, format: .currency(code: "USD"))")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`fractionLength`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatstyleconfiguration/precision/3767173-fractionlength) to specify how many decimal places you want, as a range.

```
// show 2 or more decimal places
Text("\(price, format: .currency(code: "USD").precision(.fractionLength(2...)))")
```

Also, I recommend using `Decimal` to represent prices.

```
@State private var price = Decimal(string: "2.099")!
```

Comment: Bit of a follow up, unsure if it deserves it's own question. If I'm working in cents only e.g. 209.9 cents as opposed to $2.099, can the currency formatter this like 209.9 c? Good call on using Decimal type, thank you

Comment: @TimD I'm not sure if the formatter can output in cents, but if you have a number of cents and want to format it as dollars, you can add `.scale(0.01)`. In any case this definitely deserves its own question! :)